# FFmpegで映像分割したファイルにブランクが含まれている

Tags: ffmpeg

２つの動画を分割して、指定した区間の映像を入れ替えるために
ffmpegを使用して映像の分割、結合を行っております。

しかし、入替範囲用に分割した映像の先頭数秒にブランクがあり、
例えば映像時間10秒になるように分割したにもかかわらず、出力ファイルは12秒になっているような状況です。

コマンドは

```
-ss 0 -to 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

で行っております。

結合した際にもブランク部分で映像が止まっているような状況です
ブランクが出てしまうことを抑えるにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

Comment: この記事が類似の話題で関連してそうな感じです。[FFmpeg: Cutting 3 seconds at the beginning of a video leaves 5 seconds blank](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/26302)

Comment: コマンドラインに`-c copy`（再エンコードなし）が含まれていますが、この指示を除去する（再エンコード有）と期待通りに動くでしょうか？

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます
-c copyを外して処理を行ったところ10秒で切り取り指定した通りに映像が作成されました。
ただ、再エンコードを行うことで処理時間は長くなりました。